# What is the difference between eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone and eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

when i use '**spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:2.0.1.RELEASE**',i found the local consumer side must use '**eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone**' to find registry center in remote server,but the '**eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone**' did not help.
'**eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone**' and '**eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone**' seem to represent same attribute in source code.
What is the difference between **eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone** and **eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone**?

Comment: same question, did not find an answer